# Matrix is not returning elements queried, even though I can confirm that there are elements which satisfy the query

Tags: r

I am a novice at R, so I am sorry if this question is silly. I have a matrix, "friends", which contains a bunch of integers. I also have a list of integers, "female_ids", which contains some integers. I want to replace all elements of "friends" not in "female_ids" with "NA".

So, the relevant function seems to be

```
friends[!(friends %in% female_ids)] = NA
```

But this replaces everything with `NA`! Baffled, I checked `friends[30, 10] %in% female_ids`, which turned out to be True. Then I checked `friends[friends %in% female_ids]`, which turned out to be empty. Also, I checked `friends[friends == 28]` (there are several elements equal to 28), and this turned out to be nonempty.

My question is am I missing something very obvious? I have at least one element `(30, 10)` which is definitely in female_ids. But nonetheless when I query the whole matrix it thinks nothing is in `female_ids`.

I am happy to provide any more information that would be helpful. Thank you in advance for the help!

Here is the relevant data.

```
> dput(friends)
structure(list(MF1 = c(33L, 34L, 72L, 3L, 27L, 94L, 49L, 16L, 
19L, 33L, 43L, 94L, 73L, 47L, 94L, 27L, 73L, 23L, 73L, 63L, 33L, 
43L, 86L, 16L, 4L, 3L, 33L, 76L, 72L, 86L), MF2 = c(63L, 52L, 
54L, 19L, 19L, 73L, 63L, 72L, 94L, 86L, 64L, 83L, 99L, 16L, 99L, 
73L, 82L, 61L, 94L, 16L, 94L, 16L, 61L, 16L, 82L, 82L, 4L, 76L, 
23L, 47L), MF3 = c(27L, 19L, 82L, 64L, 72L, 47L, 47L, 52L, 76L, 
23L, 34L, 4L, 63L, 52L, 34L, 72L, 3L, 73L, 16L, 73L, 86L, 3L, 
27L, 64L, 3L, 49L, 57L, 54L, 63L, 23L), MF4 = c(23L, 72L, 52L, 
34L, 33L, 61L, 73L, 3L, 47L, 52L, 57L, 76L, 23L, 4L, 27L, 82L, 
83L, 64L, 3L, 73L, 27L, 33L, 83L, 82L, 16L, 47L, 3L, 57L, 4L, 
94L), MF5 = c(16L, 57L, 57L, 82L, 99L, 64L, 4L, 34L, 73L, 3L, 
23L, 27L, 82L, 19L, 3L, 83L, 61L, 47L, 27L, 47L, 72L, 86L, 83L, 
19L, 64L, 73L, 94L, 27L, 83L, 19L), FF1 = c(81L, 21L, 50L, 45L, 
81L, 36L, 90L, 42L, 21L, 2L, 7L, 45L, 42L, 59L, 14L, 75L, 46L, 
69L, 28L, 81L, 45L, 17L, 56L, 65L, 50L, 50L, 2L, 69L, 69L, 46L
), FF2 = c(11L, 42L, 65L, 14L, 81L, 81L, 42L, 14L, 28L, 7L, 56L, 
7L, 90L, 28L, 11L, 65L, 65L, 90L, 45L, 67L, 91L, 67L, 14L, 56L, 
65L, 67L, 14L, 46L, 78L, 45L), FF3 = c(62L, 7L, 62L, 56L, 69L, 
17L, 7L, 28L, 2L, 5L, 46L, 56L, 59L, 14L, 2L, 56L, 56L, 14L, 
21L, 36L, 78L, 62L, 11L, 59L, 62L, 45L, 70L, 17L, 14L, 56L), 
    FF4 = c(91L, 67L, 42L, 50L, 45L, 56L, 2L, 11L, 7L, 14L, 17L, 
    17L, 62L, 50L, 62L, 2L, 78L, 75L, 91L, 11L, 28L, 69L, 70L, 
    78L, 45L, 5L, 56L, 2L, 42L, 70L), FF5 = c(45L, 75L, 70L, 
    78L, 36L, 42L, 21L, 7L, 36L, 11L, 28L, 14L, 36L, 36L, 28L, 
    14L, 67L, 56L, 70L, 28L, 46L, 81L, 45L, 90L, 42L, 21L, 67L, 
    90L, 11L, 28L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))

> dput(female_ids)
c(42L, 56L, 14L, 75L, 11L, 28L, 78L, 65L, 81L, 36L, 90L, 62L, 
50L, 69L, 7L)
```

Comment: Could you post what your data looks like with `dput()`? It seems you're on the right track with `%in%`, but it's hard to say without knowing what `friends` or `female_ids` look like exactly.

Comment: Yup, I added it. Thank you!

Comment: `friends[which(!sapply(friends, \`%in%\`, female_ids), arr.ind = T)] <- NA`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `friends` is not a `matrix` but a `data.frame`. The problem is apparent if you run:

```
friends %in% female_ids
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The output is not a 30 by 10 matrix. It doesn't check for each element if it is in the `female_ids` vector. So if you first run `friends <- as.matrix(friends)` followed by `friends[!(friends %in% female_ids)] = NA` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep `friends` as a `data.frame`, you could do

```
friends[apply(friends, 2, function(x) !(x %in% female_ids))] = NA
```

But I suspect converting to a matrix first could be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant way of achieving what you want is using the `dplyr` package to manipulate the data frame directly, and the `mutate_all` verb does exactly what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
friends <- friends %>% mutate_all(function(x){ ifelse(x %in% female_ids, x, NA) })
```

I think using `dplyr` verbs might be a lot more natural than using base R's subsetting syntax in situations like these.